# DT and Shiny: Formatting numbers in a datatable with filters

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app with a datatable, and I would like to have 2 things done:

1. I'd like to add the filters at the top of the DTOutput
2. I'd like to have the numbers in the table formatted as percentages.

I can only achieve one or the other. So if I only use the filters (see attempt #3 in the code) it works, but I cannot format the numbers as percentages. If I try to format the numbers (see attpemts #1 and #2 in the code) then the filters disappear but the numbers are correctly formatted. I also get warning message in the console:

> "renderDataTable ignores ... arguments when expr yields a datatable
>   object"

which doesn't help me much, since I am quite new to Shiny and R.

I found tutorials and answered questions for either formatting numbers or filtering tables, but I am obviously missing something... If you can guide me to an answer or spot a mistake in the code below I would be thankful.

reproducible `app.R` here:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("start", "Click to Start") 
  DTOutput('tbl1'),
  DTOutput('tbl2'),
  DTOutput('tbl3')
)

# Define Server
server = function(input, output) {

  #Attempt #1: gives me the formatted numbers but no filter.
  x <- eventReactive(input$start, iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species == "setosa") %>% datatable %>% formatPercentage(2:3, digits=2))
  output$tbl1<-  DT::renderDT(x(), filter="top")


  #Attempt #2: gives me the formatted numbers but no filter.
  y <- eventReactive(input$start, iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species == "setosa"))
  output$tbl2 <-  DT::renderDT(y() %>% datatable %>% formatPercentage(2:3, digits=2), filter="top")


  #Attempt #3: I get the filter, if I don't try to format the numbers
  z <- eventReactive(input$start, iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species == "setosa"))
  output$tbl3 <-  DT::renderDT(z(), filter="top")


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like yo forgot to use the `datatable()` function in your 3rd attempt. Here's what you need -

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("start", "Click to Start"),
  DTOutput('tbl3')
)

# Define Server
server = function(input, output) {

  z <- eventReactive(input$start, {
    iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species == "setosa")
  })

  output$tbl3 <-  DT::renderDT({
    datatable(z(), filter="top") %>% 
      formatPercentage(2:3, digits=2)
  })     
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```